# Stack Overflow's Mini Profiler

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5, mvc-mini-profiler

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

This looks amazing, and I'm really excited about it, but my site is IIS 7.5/ASP.NET 4 **webforms**. I looked at the FAQ, but I couldn't find much. Will this work for me? Are there additional steps I would need to take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Based on this sample](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/#hg/Sample.WebForms), I would say it does work on Web Forms.